# How to write JavaScript form validations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, forms, jquery

Please suggest any source of information(Screencast or Article) to read about Javascript form validation in Rails. I have searched railscasts.com for the screencasts related to this topic , however, I wasn't able to find any article specifically dedicated to this topic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) as it makes it very easy, using this plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation.

Comment: Is there any ruby gem for performing Javascript validations in Rails3?

Comment: [This article](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) includes examples on how to use jQuery with Rails 3.